# Android MQTT Client unable to reconnect to ActiveMQ

Tags: java, android, activemq-classic, mqtt

I'm using MQTT in android to communicate with an ActiveMQ server. I used this example to implement the android mqtt client: http://dalelane.co.uk/blog/?p=1599.
When I first open the android app it connects to the ActiveMQ and everything works.
When I close the application, delete the app data and reopen the android to try and reconnect to ActiveMQ I get the following error in ActiveMQ:

```
2013-09-29 19:25:50,064 | WARN  | Transport Connection to: tcp://192.168.0.108:54395 failed: java.io.EOFException | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection.Transport | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///192.168.0.108:54395@1883
2013-09-29 20:18:20,417 | WARN  | Failed to add Connection ID:32132151513546-2:5, reason: javax.jms.InvalidClientIDException: Broker: localhost - Client: dbasdfasdfe0b already connected from tcp://192.168.0.108:59211 | org.apache.activemq.broker.TransportConnection | ActiveMQ Transport: tcp:///192.168.0.108:36745@1883
```

I'm guessing it has something to do with not disconnecting from the server before trying to reconnect. Maybe I can configure ActiveMQ to delete the unused connection and disconnect the client sooner when ActiveMQ figures that the client got disconnected?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I ended up changing ActiveMQ keep-alive by configuring this line in activemq.xml:

```
<transportConnector name="mqtt" uri="mqtt://0.0.0.0:1883?transport.defaultKeepAlive=10000"/>
```

And configuring the MQTT android client keep alive like so:

```
keepAliveSeconds = 5;
mqttClient.connect(mqttClientId, true, keepAliveSeconds);
```

I read that the client keep alive should be less than the server, this is why I choose 5 and 10 seconds. I hope this is the right amount of time for a real time application.